# jQuery namespace is not a function

Tags: jquery

Everytime I try to run the following code I get a:

**.call is not a function**

I can't figure out what is going on as this is a pretty straightforward piece of code.
I must be missing something really obvious here.  Thanks for the help. If possible please
try to include code samples still learning here.

```
;(function($){

$.fn.call = function() { 

var CLICK = 'click';

function ClickCall(event) {
    var $call = $(event.target).closest('.call-survey');

     if ($call.find('#yes').is(':checked')) {
         $call.find('.call-survey fieldset').hide();
     } else {
         $call.find('div.call-survey-no').show();
         $call.find('#yes').addClass('left');

     }
}

return this.each(function() {
        var $call = $(this);
        $call.on(CLICK, '#chatForm', ClickCall);
});

};
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () { $('.call-survey').call(); });
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/A2WsL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is a reserved name in JavaScript. It has to do with `call` and `apply` with functions.

I suggest changing it.

Comment: Where can you find that info? [MDN's JavaScript Reserved Words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) doesn't show it.

Comment: I tried changing it to userCall and still getting the same error.

Comment: Not necessarily reserved, it just already exists. in this case it's being overridden which could cause issues, however it shouldn't be causing the error described.